# How to update ip in hosts file automatically from a VirtualBox guest?

Tags: virtualbox, hostname, network-interface

I have a VirtualBox guest running Debian with **Bridged Adapter**. The host is running on Windows 8. I would like to connect **from the host to the guest** through a specific port. I came up with the following strategy:

1. Detect ip change in Debian
2. Get it using `ip addr show eth0 | grep -oP '(?<=inet )([^/]+)'`
3. Setup C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc as shared folder
4. Allow permissions for VirtualBox to update the hosts file
5. Update the hosts file from the guest assigning the ip of the guest to a name

Now I came up with the following approach:

1. Elude *IP change* detection by running a cron every 5 minutes
2. Run ip script
3. Setup shared folder
4. Run VirtualBox as administrator in Windows 8
5. Update hosts file.

I only have problems with step 1 and 4 which don't seem elegant. Does it exist a better approach to get the host aware of the guest's ip?

Comment: Do you have access to the dhcp server? It's likely easier to configure it to hand out the same address to the VM guest every time.

Comment: I run this guest on a personal laptop. Some times I need to work on Debian and Windows in parallel because of *reasons*. This may happen at home or at the office. Both DHCP servers are common cisco/dlink routers.